Configure different event loop group for each client
I have following Micronaut configuration to have a separate event loop group for client-a, because the calls to client-a are taking some time to return response and this is affecting performance of other client.
micronaut:
  http:
    client:
      event-loop-group: http-client
    services:
      client-a:
        url: "http://localhost:8080"
        path: "/api/v1"
        event-loop-group: a-client
      client-b:
        url: "http://localhost:8081"
        path: "/api/v1"
      client-c:
        url: "http://localhost:8082"
        path: "/api/v1"
  netty:
    event-loops:
      default:
        num-threads: 16
      http-client:
        num-threads: 30
      a-client:
        num-threads: 10

I have created a declarative client like this:
@Client(value = "client-a")
public interface ClientA {

    @Post(uri = "/hello", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Single<String> hello(String name);
}

However the calls to ClientA are executed on http-client event loop. Am I missing something in the configuration and Is it possible to configure separate event loops for each client.

eventLoopGroup lives in abstract class HttpClientConfiguration. Descendant DefaultHttpClientConfiguration is used for micronaut.http.client. Descendant ServiceHttpClientConfiguration is used for micronaut.http.services. micronaut.http.services.*.event-loop-group is read correctly from config, but is not used in the code. You should probably report this issue.
